# SWRevealViewController, prevent from hitting viewdidload

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

So I am using SWRevealViewController to do the slide out drawer UI.
One of my ViewControllers hosts a Map, and I allow the user to do things on that map and customize. I noticed that every time I move between front and back VC's using

```
SWRevealViewController
```

that when it goes to a previously loaded ViewController it always calls

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

Is there a way to suppress that? 
Shouldn't SWRevealViewController maintain a list of previosly loaded Viewcontrollers just to make sure it doesn't reload one again? this doesn't work if I need to maintain state in my ViewControllers.

Comment: Have u got the solution to this problem.. pls help i am struck with the same